# Jquery click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with bootstrap accordion. I want to be able to store the state of the accordion. I decided to use localstorage. I want to clear localstorage if the user has closed the accordion so it doesn't keep opening. I have all this done. My question is, when the user clicks on the link to open/close the accordion I am doing a check for the class 'collapsed'. When it is clicked I assume if it has class 'collapsed' I can clear localstorage. But for some reason its the opposite. If I negate it all is well. What am I not seeing?

```
  $('.accordion-right').click(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('collapsed')) {
      localStorage.clear();
    } else {
      localStorage.setItem('collapseItem', $(this).attr('href'));
    }
  });

  var collapseItem = localStorage.getItem('collapseItem');
  if (collapseItem) {
    if (<%= is_patient? %>) {
      $('#record').collapse('show');
    } else {
      $(collapseItem).collapse('show');
    }
  }
```

Heres a snippet of html

```
           <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="accordion-right" href="#history"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th">
                </span>History</a>
              </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="history" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <ul>
                  <%= nav_search_sidebar %>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

edit: spelling

For clarity, when the bootstrap event fires it removes the class 'collapsed' which is added dynamically when the code runs.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dwy8e3d8/) for it and is normal that It won't work your code? I have tried in my own IDE and its giving me errors for this: `<%= nav_search_sidebar %>` I don't understand what that does? Maybe explain it? 
Are you sure that your localstorage is cleared? I use this for being sure the local storage with this key is cleared: `localStorage.removeItem('collapseItem');`